# Hibernate Schema-validation error for the inherited entity class

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Here is my inherited sub entity as follows:-

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "SUB_TABLE")
@DiscriminatorValue("R")
public class SubTable extends BaseAudit {

    @Column(name = "REV", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private long rev;
    @Column(name = "REVTYPE", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private long revType;

    @Column(name = "active_from", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Instant activeFrom;
    @Column(name = "active_to", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Instant activeTo;

    public SubTable() {
    }
  }
```

My base entity as follow:-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BASE_AUDIT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "derive_type")
public abstract class BaseAudit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    public Long version;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    public String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    public Instant created;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    public String updatedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    public Instant updated;

    @Column(name = "derive_type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public String deriveType;

}
```

I will have many sub entity will be inherited from this BaseAudit entity. I got following error:-

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
> Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
> Schema-validation: missing column [active_to] in table [base_audit]

So it complain about the missing column active_to for the base entity. But this column is from the sub entity. I don't need this to the base entity. I will have many other sub entity and only the common ones are in the base entity. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `@Inheritance(strategy = SINGLE_TABLE)` does exactly what it says on the tin - all the data regarding both parent and child entities is cramped together in a single table.

This means `@Table(name = "SUB_TABLE")` is simply ignored, as you specifically instructed to put all the data for `SubTable` into the parent's `BASE_AUDIT` table. Since `BASE_AUDIT` does not have the necessary columns (`REV`, `REVTYPE`, `active_from`, `active_to`), you're getting schema validation errors.

Are you sure `@MappedSuperclass` is not what you want instead of `@Inheritance`?